# Sigma (sum) Problem

Tags: calculus, summation

What's the answer for the sum with
$$ \sum_{r=0}^n \left(\frac 34 \right)^r $$

I got $4\left(1-\left(\frac 34 \right)^n\right)$ but apparently it's wrong. My work is provided in the picture uploaded.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lS8ti.jpg) Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try it for $n=1,2$ and it should become obvious.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{r=0}^n \left(\frac 34 \right)^r$$ is the sum of a geometric sequence, namely $$  1+(\frac {3}{4}) +(\frac {3}{4})^2 +...+  (\frac {3}{4})^n$$

We know that $$1 + r +r^2 + ...+ r^n = \frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$

Thus  $$\sum_{r=0}^n \left(\frac 34 \right)^r = \frac{(3/4)^{n+1}-1}{(3/4)-1}= 4\left(1-\left(\frac {3}{4} \right)^{n+1}\right)  $$

Answer (score 0):

The formula for $1+x+\cdots + x^n$ is $\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$. So replace $n$ by $n+1$ in your answer and you are good to go!

Comment: So everything in my answer is good except the (3/4) should be raised to n+1 rather than n?

Also, I thought the formula was (1 - x^n)/(1 - x)? How come x is raised to n + 1 rather than just n?

Comment: Yes. If your formula was as you wrote, then the sum just went to $n-1$.